# Are Stack Overflow chatrooms still available?

Tags: support, chat

[image]I've used chatrooms for Stack Overflow earlier. Is it still available? When I go to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) I get the message above. It's happening for a few weeks or more.

Comment: Sure: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Did you consider, well, you know... checking... before asking?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Please see my updated question

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried but it redirects

Comment: @Shog9 I tried. But I could't. Please see my updated question

Comment: So.... did you think of telling us what went wrong? You know, so that we will have a chance to help you?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know. I've use that link before for an old account. Now its not getting

Comment: As Shog says [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5289998#5289998), you need to contact SE via the "contact us" link in the bottom,  and ask to fix your chat profile. Good luck! :)

Comment: @qwerty Your chat profile should be all fixed up. Please let me know if you're still experiencing issues.

Comment: @AdamLear Thank you. Everything looks fine and good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [chat profile](//chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5505865/qwerty) is broken.

This is the result of accounts merging, the merge does not apply for chat, leaving the chat account broken.

As far as I know, only SE employee (Community  Manager or a Developer) can fix that, so try contacting them via the "contact us" form and ask to fix your chat account.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check this